# Help translating seals, and phrase

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

I was wondering if anyone could help with the translation of this seal And characters, this are the only photos that i have right now.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: First image, the four big characters are 慈悲(mercy)平和(peace). This should be something related to Buddhism. For the seals in the second image, the first one is 佛X. The second is Y林. I could not figure out the X, and Y. Maybe someone else here can.

Comment: To me it looks like Y is 道, so 道林 when read from the right (林道 in the seal)

Comment: seems like 傳彿 to me... but Chinese reads right to left, the two seals should be 彿傳 and  趙林

Answer (score 3):

The four large characters say 「慈悲平安」 (*benevolence and peace*).

---

The two seals say:

[image: 佛海]

「佛海」, *The [world of Buddhahood](https://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/dic/Content/W/49) is as vast as the ocean* (佛界如海)

[image: 林]

「⿺辵（道）林」, literally *Forest of [Ways](https://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/dic/Content/W/6)*, probably an [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name).

Comment: the last character read as “安”  omg 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 well, that's my guess. What do you think?

Comment: semantically, i agree with you. well, it just lacks the features of the top component “ 宀” (the horizontal stroke). further, “慈悲平安” sounds odd. a more “buddhism” phrase would be “慈悲喜捨” 